# Android app crashes when rotating the "Getting preview" or "Posting edit" dialog

Tags: bug, edits, android-app

App version: 1.0.52

When you edit a question and rotate the screen while the "Getting preview" or "Posting edit" dialog is showing the app will crash.

```
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): Process: com.stackexchange.marvin, PID: 4768
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42440ba0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} not attached to window manager
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:370)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:329)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:312)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.OperationThatCanFail$1.onPostExecute(OperationThatCanFail.java:81)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at com.stackexchange.marvin.core.OperationThatCanFail$1.onPostExecute(OperationThatCanFail.java:67)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
12-25 21:38:07.033 E/AndroidRuntime(4768): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 21:38:07.035 W/ActivityManager(27384):   Force finishing activity com.stackexchange.marvin/.ui.AskOrEditQuestionActivity
```

Comment: Still repro'd on v1.0.83. A classic crash due to the app losing the reference of the dialog after screen rotation.